# Configuração PHPStorm 2017.1.1 + Lavarel 5.3 - Problemas no roteamento / Execução do projeto

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, phpstorm

Dae pessoALL... preciso de ajuda na configuração do projeto, pois acredito que seja isso o problema.

Cenário: Cliente comprou um site, carinha fez e abandonou, sumiu, cheio de erro e funcionando pela metade...
Cliente me procurou só com o link do site e o acesso da hospedagem
Baixei o fontes, configurei, NetBeans, não rodou...
Partiu PhpStorm, criei projeto e adicionei os fontes, ativei o plugin do Lavarel (peguei a versão pelo arquivo do framework mesmo), segui o passo a passo da instalação daqui... 
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Tudo certo, ate aqui...

Ai instalei e atualizei as dependências existentes no composer.json,
Rodei os comandos:
artisan ide-helper:generate
artisan server executamos o servidor local:8000
Então configurei o PS para iniciar em index.ph no public do projeto (usando wamp)

No inspecionar elemento, a url aponta para o metodo do controlador, mais o request http não chega lá, deve ser alguma configuração de roteamento ou coisa do tipo no proprio PhpStorm.

A Pagina inicial carrega, porém quando clico em qualquer link, ele redireciona para uma pagina \em-breve, e não para o controlador do link

[image: Sequencia]

Agradeço ajuda desde já! Obrigado!

Comment: Está muito vago isso.. poderia mostrar o seu arquivo de rotas?

Comment: Sim, apenas o codigo, não consigo postar imagem...

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Oferta'], function () {
        //Route::get('/oferta/categoria/{slug}', ['as' => 'front.oferta.categoria', 'uses' => 'CategoriaController@categoria'])->where('slug', '(.*)');
        Route::get('/oferta/dados', ['as' => 'front.oferta.registarInteresse', 'uses' => 'OfertaController@interesse']);
        Route::get('/oferta/{slug}', ['as' => 'front.oferta.oferta', 'uses' => 'OfertaController@oferta']);
    });

Comment: E o resultado de artisan route:list

|        | GET|HEAD | /                                                              | front.index                                     | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FrontController@index                                        | web              |

Comment: |        | GET|HEAD | anunciar                                                       | front.usuario.anunciar                          | App\Http\Controllers\Usuario\AnunciarController@step1                                   | web,usuario      |